Remove muntins from old sidelight windows?
So I own a home that came with all the typical builder-grade materials and I’m now working on replacing my interior trim. I went to case out my front door and sidelight windows as a single unit, but then I noticed the jambs of my door were rotted and needed to be replaced. In order to replace the jambs, I had to then remove the brick moldings (also rotted at the bottom).

While removing all these materials, I disturbed the sidelights in such a way that one of the muntins knocked loose and fell down inside the window. My research so far has told me that there’s basically no saving the window when this happens because the windows are made with a vacuum and special gas between the panes of glass, and as soon as that vacuum is exposed to the atmosphere, it can never be truly repaired. Some mention that it will fog up, etc…
Well, we never particularly cared much for the classic look of the sidelights in the first place. One of the first things we did when we bought the house was remove the window dressings from them (something I’d find in my grandmas house), and added a frosted look to the windows so that strangers couldn’t just walk up to our front door and see inside.
People warn about breaking the vacuum seal of the windows because it could then cause them to fog up. My question is, since I don’t care about the windows being perfectly clear to see through, might I have have some special liberties to “mess” with the windows for DIY repair and it be perfectly fine since I have them masked with the frosted look anyways?

One idea I have is to drill a small hole into the side of the window frame. I just so happen to uniquley have access to the side of the window because I’m in the middle of replacing the exterior trim work.
I would insert a little BB into the drilled hole and use a neodymium magnet to guide the BB to pull the muntin back in place. I don’t imagine the Munion would stay there without some kind of adhesive or mechanical fastener, so I might then try to just keep the magnet and BB in place as inconspicuously as I can get it. Then I’d do whatever I can to plug the drilled hole, air-tight (JB Weld?) ‍♂️
My other idea is to take it a step further and use the magnet to guide the BB all up and around the insides of the window, between the glass panels, knocking ALL the muntins loose, and try to feed them OUT of the window completely in order to be left with a full length window with no muntins at all.
Seeing how this first muntin so easily knocked loose, I’m confident they don’t provide any structural support nor any other utility – they’re just there for looks.
What are y’all’s thought on this? Am I risking facing something else more disastrous than some moisture just fogging up the insides of these windows by doing this? If that’s the only thing in my way, then I’m just a dab of JB Weld away from tinkering around and ending up with windows that I’ll be much happier with the looks of, without having to drop hundreds and hundreds of dollars on ordering a new set of custom fit windows and all my other work being delayed until those would arrive.

Why not simply replace the panel in its entirety with a new IGU?

@Huesmann: I'm guessing the answer is cost. Even if just replacing the glass, it's not exactly cheap. On the other hand, replacing the insulated glass panel would also let you pick something you like better. (PS: rather than frosting, you could consider mock stained glass, or glass paints if you're feeling artistic. I've seen some nice things done just with overlapped pieces of painter's tape.)

@keshlam well, the old one may not have failed yet, but the intended fix would certainly make it fail.  There's "cheap" and there's "right," and there's not a lot of overlap.

The proposed fix would certainly degrade performance, and is not one I'd recommend. But it'd still be slightly better than a single-pane window, if it could be done without shattering the glass, which would be my concern. Personally this is one I'd try to ask the manufacturer about, since that kind of failure really shouldn't happen.
